# java library to determine cpu and memory used by a program during its execution

Tags: java, memory-management, cpu-usage

I want to measure the level of CPU and memory utilisation of a java program, preferably with a GUI and graphs showing exact utilisation levels throughout the period of execution of the program.

Is there a library/framework that does this?

Also, i would prefer if I could measure such usage for a program(either desktop or web app) that runs on local system or remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse TPTP : http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/

It contains very good tools to follow the threads as well as the memory and cpu consumption, all inside a clear GUI. As every java profiler, it can be configured to follow a remote java program.

If you're using Eclipse as your IDE, this is a natural choice.

Answer (score 1):

[JProfiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JProfiler) is good to start with. You can connect it to a local or a remote java process and profile the application to understand the memory usage and various other performance counters.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) will be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Also try [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), it's absolutely and free bundled in oracle jdk(don't know about openjdk).